# compile gdal with ESRI FileGDB_API Ubuntu

Tags: gdal, esri-geodatabase, ubuntu, ubuntugis

I'm trying to build GDAL on Ubuntu 16.04 with ESRI FileGDB_API driver support. I've followed the instructions here: https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FileGDB and have attempted to pass the location of proj included with the ESRI FileGDB_API. Here is my configure command:

```
./configure --with-static-proj=/usr/local/FileGDB_API/lib/libFileGDBAPI.so --with-fgdb=/usr/local/FileGDB_API
```

And the error:

```
configure: error: --without-static-proj and --with-fgdb are both available. There might be some incompatibility between system libproj and the embedded copy within libFileGDBAPI
```

I get the same error if I remove `--with-static-proj` and if I use `--without-static-proj`.

I'm attempting to compile gdal 2.3.1 and I'm using the FileGDB_API version 1.5 for gcc 5.1.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get past this error by installing `libproj-dev` (ubuntu) and running

```
./configure --with-static-proj4 --with-fgdb=/usr/local/path
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stackexchange! As a new user, please be sure to take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).